# Allow hyphen in htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently this rules doesn't allow me to have hyphens on the url string value. When I remove the hyphen from any url string it works.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine on

## Prevent Directory Listing
IndexIgnore *

## Make pages render without their extension in the url
Options +MultiViews

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d
RewriteRule  ^.*$  -  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  ^.*$  -  [L]

RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5 [QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I have tried changing the rule few times after following some tutorials but doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5 [QSA]
```

**Example Link:**

http://www.example.com/mp3-series/all-albums

**How can I cater for the hyphen in the url string value?**

Comment: `([-\w]+)` should work. Which link are you trying to access?

Comment: @hjpotter92 http://www.example.com/mp3-series/all-albums

Comment: @RedVirus Your current rule should already work for that, what issue are you having? You rule should pick from 1 to 3 levels of path without problems. `[-\w]` means any alphanumeric character and dash.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in in `/mp3-series/` folder?